# How to extend the functionality of this Angularjs/json/markdown code?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, markdown

So I'm currently working on extending the functionality of this pattern library application called Tapestry (https://github.com/PebbleRoad/tapestry). Currently the application is able to read JSON and Markdown data and then display it in the user perspective.

What it's doing right now is going through a markdown file using a plugin called 'Marked' (https://github.com/chjj/marked) and extracting the content, seperating it into a description and content. The following is a sample of a Markdown file:

```
    ---
name: Accordion
description: |
  ### What
  Puts modules of content into a linear stack of panels that can be closed and opened independently of each other. The accordion also helps in shortening a page and making it more scannable.

  ### Use when
  The content modules are mutually exclusive. Content modules can consist of a list of items, links or text blocks. 

---
<!-- Accordion-->
<div class="ui-accordion">
    <div class="accordion__header">Accordion item 1</div>
    <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporial incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At enim ad minim veniam,</p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__header">Accordion item 3</div>
    <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporial incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At enim ad minim veniam,</p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__header">Accordion item 3</div>
    <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporial incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At enim ad minim veniam,</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- / Accordion  -->
```

Now for my purposes I need to extend the funcitonality by being able to also include the Javascript and CSS of each component, unfortunately I'm not to familiar with Angular or Marked for that matter and I can't seem to do this by adding an additional label in the markdown and attempting to process it.

This is the current angular directive that processes all the information.

```
.directive('rawInclude', [
     '$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$q', '$timeout',
        function ($http, $templateCache, $compile, $q, $timeout) {

            var totalcount = 0                  

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                terminal: true,
                scope: {
                    patterns: '='
                },
                compile: function (telement, attr) {

                    var srcExp = attr.src, count = 0;

                    return function (scope, element) {

                        scope.$watch('patterns', function(newValue){

                            if(newValue){
                                if(scope.patterns && scope.patterns.children) totalcount = scope.patterns.children.length
                            }
                        }, true)

                        var changeCounter = 0


                        scope.$watch(srcExp, function (src) {

                            var thisChangeId = ++changeCounter;                             

                            if (src) {


                                $http.get(src, { cache: $templateCache }).success(function (response) {

                                    if (thisChangeId !== changeCounter) return;

                                    /* Increment counter */

                                    count++;

                                    /**
                                     * Parsing Markdown files
                                     * @type {Object}
                                     */

                                    var parsedContent = {                    
                                        yaml: '',
                                        markdown: '', 
                                        html: '',
                                        meta: {}
                                    };

                                    var re = /^(-{3}(?:\n|\r)([\w\W]+?)-{3})?([\w\W]*)*/
                                          , results = re.exec(response.trim())
                                          , conf = {}
                                          , yamlOrJson,
                                          name = "content"

                                    if((yamlOrJson = results[2])) {

                                        if(yamlOrJson.charAt(0) === '{') { 
                                            conf = JSON.parse(yamlOrJson);
                                        } else {
                                            conf = jsyaml.load(yamlOrJson);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    conf[name] = results[3] ? results[3] : '';


                                    /* Add description */

                                    var $description = element.parent().next();

                                    if(conf.description){

                                        parsedContent.markdown = marked(conf.description);                  

                                        $description.html(parsedContent.markdown)

                                    }else{

                                        /* If there is no description: Hide it */

                                        $description.hide()
                                    }

                                    /* Element preview */

                                    element.html(conf.content)

                                    /* Compile Angular directives */

                                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);

                                    /* Trigger element added */

                                    if(count == totalcount) {

                                        $timeout(function(){

                                            angular.element('body').trigger('tapestry.completed')   
                                        },500)                                          

                                    }


                                    /* Element Syntax highlight */

                                    var code = element.closest('.block--example').find('code.html');
                                    var jscode = element.closest('.block--example').find('code.js');
                                            $element = element.clone();



                                    /* Adds codes to the code block */

                                    code.text(conf.content.trim());
                                    jscode.text(results[2]);

                                    /* Highlighting */

                                    Prism.highlightElement(code[0]);
                                    Prism.highlightElement(jscode[0]);


                                }).error(function () {

                                    if (thisChangeId === changeCounter) element.html('');

                                });
                            }

                            else element.html('');

                        });


                    };




                 },

                 link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                    if(scope.$last){
                        console.log("hey")  
                    }

                 }
            };
     }])
```

I added the jscode bit. Obviously this is a very specific problem but I'm sure anyone with a bit of Angular knowledge will be able to assist. Thank you in advanced and I look forward to hearing your answer.

Apologies if the question is unclear.

I need to be able to add and parse other sections to the markdown file. for example, an area for css, an area for JS etc. How would this be done?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry if that's if it's unclear. I need to be able to add and parse other sections to the markdown file. for example, an area for css, an area for JS etc. How would this be done?